# How to apply a function to selected columns?

Tags: r, function, sorting, select

I am doing an analysis - I have imported .csv file with 66 columns. In which first column is character and rest all are dbl. I want to convert the mvalues into betavalues for the dbl variables in all the columns except the first column as it is character variable.

I have an excel file containing 66 columns -
If am applying the function for mvalues into betavalues conversion without any selection like
`Betavalues <- m2beta(Mvalues)` - I am getting an error - `Error in 2^m : non-numeric argument to binary operator.` As the first column is a character, not numeric am getting this error.

I have downloaded dplyr and tidyverse and then I was trying to do with `select()` to select columns except first one - `Mvalues2 <- select(Mvalues, c(-'PROBES'))`  - am not able to get it and getting an error - `no applicable method for 'select' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'character')"`. Maybe I am using it wrong.  How can I solve this issue? Can you help solve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: You should try to first convert your `Mvalues` object to a `tibble` or `data.frame`.